# How to make a Dynamic/Optional Filter(parameters) in mongo DB query at (Jasper Studio)

Tags: sql, mongodb, jasper-reports

I'm creating a web aplication and it's working perfectly, but at the end user need to create a report from it's data.

On the report page I created some txt boxes where users will type for filtering. Those txt boxes could be empty and I need to return everything from the DB, or some parameter could be filled. Remenbering that I need to pass txt boxes content as params to JasperServer and they will be used in the Query.

A example of data input is:

```
    txtName= empty (null), 
    txtCity= 'Belo Horizonte'
```

It should generate a report with all record of people how lives in Belo Horizonte no matter the name.

I made it in SQL and works perfect. After I tried to use the same logic on mongo but it doesn't work. I have tried with $lt, $gt, $lte, $gte, $exist, $ne and bunch other aggregation tool and I was not able to make it propertly.

SQL:

```
select * from myfirstreports 
where ($P{city} is null or cidade =$P{city}) 
AND ($P{name} is null or nome =$P{name})
```

Mongo:

```
{
    'collectionName' : 'myfirstreports',

   'findFields' : 
    {
        'nome': 1, 'numeros': 1, 'vulgo': 1, 'cidade': 1, 
        'usuResponsavelCadastro': 1, 'created_at': 1
    },

    findQuery  : 
    {
        $and: [ 
            {$or:[{ $P{city}: {$eq: null}}, {'cidade': $P{city}}]}, 
            { $or:[{$P{name}: {'$eq': null}}, {'nome': $P{name}}]}
                    ]
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following expression:

```
$P{city}.equals(null)? "{ }" : "{'cidade': '$P!{city}'}"//Need to create a non prompting parameter
$P{name}.equals(null)? "{ }":  "{'nome': '$P!{name}'}"
```

$P!{...} parameters allows me to create a query as a string and pass to JasperSoft report.